# How to accept YY/MM/DD format in google sheets

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm running some code that uses and inputs a report from another system and uses the data. That report includes a column of dates in the format YY/MM/DD. When I try to work with that data the spreadsheet as well as my code it interprets it as DD/MM/YY. ex. July 16th, 2019 is interpreted as July 19th, 2016.

Having read a number of other posts I realize this is an issue of what locale the spreadsheet is formatted in. I've tried a bunch of formats but can't find a locale that is formatted in YY/MM/DD

Is there a locale that is formatted YY/MM/DD?
Is there some other workaround that i can easily convert these dates? Over time I will have a lot of data, manual adjustment and individual find/replace are not options.

Worst case scenario I guess I can go store the data in an array and loop through it editing it as a string to shift he "YY" and "DD" but this seems inefficient and like there should be some built in functionality.

Edit:
At the request of those below here is a link to a test sheet that shows the ongoing concern.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fLboQyF1ChEAFCpXTeDMU6su55oTgi67EpO_5MTPIdQ/edit?usp=sharing

Also, some sample code:

```
 if (Utilities.formatDate(new Date(SelectionList[y][0]), timeZone, 'yyyy-MMM-dd') == Utilities.formatDate(new Date(TotalData[x][2]), timeZone, 'yyyy-MMM-dd')) {
      //SelectionList[y][0] == TotalData[x][2]) {
      var Surgeon = SelectionList[y][1];
      break;
          }
      }
```

As you can see I'm calling two dates from two arrays (SelectionList[y][0] and TotalData[x][2]) and then trying to find the point where they are equal. SelectionList is a constant that I created and therefore formatted it DD/MM/YYYY because I knew this was a format that worked. TotalData is report generated and is autopopulated in YY/MM/DD. When I attempt to use Utilities.FormatDate the script misinterprets TotalData Dates due to this. To be honest I'm less concerned about the script because I know why it doesn't work. If I can fix the way the spreadsheet interprets the original date then the script would work just fine.

In editing this response one other thing I've noticed is that when I select a give cell while the cell shows formatted date of 18/07/16 the formula bar shows 2016-07-18 clearly showing that the spreadsheet interprets the 16 as the YY.

As well, I'm looking at data on a month by month basis. other months have worked without issue. I see now the error occurs because this month start didn't have any data in the first two weeks. Months that have started at the beginning such as 19/06/02 have automatically been interpreted as YY/MM/DD for a reason that escapes me.  This does not work the same in my test sheet.

Comment: Is the imported data interpreted as a date or as a string? Could you by any chance provide a sample of the code you are working on, as well as a sanitized sample of the spreadsheet? That would be really useful in order to solve your issue.

Comment: @lamblichus - I've edited the original post to include a sample spreadsheet and some code but as mentioned in my edit I'm not worried about the code. The issue is in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

see if that doesn't help you in something!

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work since the sheet is confused about what is the year and what is the day. ie A1 = 18/07/16, when i apply your formula "=TEXT(A1;"YYYY/MM/DD") the output is 2016/07/18. All buit in formatting funtions appear to function the same way because the spreadsheet is convinced it the cell is July 18th 2016, instead of July 16th 2018.

Answer (score 0):

You can also go in your top menu `Format -> Number -> Other Format -> Other format date and time` and then choose which one you want

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work since the sheet is confused about what is the year and what is the day. ie A1 = 18/07/16, when i apply any custom formatting from the menu such as "YYYY/MM/DD" the output is 2016/07/18. All built in formatting functions appear to function the same way because the spreadsheet is convinced it the cell is July 18th 2016, instead of July 16th 2018.

Comment: Did you try to put ' front of your date as it can recognize it as a string and then format it?

Comment: This doesn't make any difference as the spreadsheet still thinks the first digits are DD and last digits are YY. As well, if at all possible I don't want to have to edit the spreadsheet data manually as this is copied from another automatically generated report.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the dates you want to change are in column A, starting at row 2, I wrote a small code that changes the date the way you want:

```
function changeDates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var values = sheet.getRange("A2:A").getValues();
  for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var value = values[i][0];
    var date = new Date(value);
    var day = date.getYear().toString();
    if(day.length == 4) { 
      day = day.slice(2); // Remove first two characters if input format has four characters (i.e. '2018')
    };
    var year = date.getDate();
    if(year.length == 2) { // Add '20' or '200' to the year depending on current day format
      year = '20'.concat(year);
    } else if(year.length == 1) {
      year = '200'.concat(year);
    }
    date.setDate(day);
    date.setYear(year);
    sheet.getRange(2 + i, 1).setValue(date);
  };
};
```

I hope this is of any help.

Comment: It helps for the given solution but I'd really like to find a way to set the default so I can avoid this issue completely. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't think you can do this using no function whatsoever.